# Buscar datos en un JSON

Tags: php, json

me gustaría saber como buscar datos dentro de un JSON por medio de PHP.
Tengo un código JSON que contiene un listado inmenso de ciudades con sus códigos id y quiero que el usuario pregunte una ciudad y el programa escrito en PHP busque la ciudad dentro del json, vea las ciudades similares, le devuelva al usuario aquellas coincidencias, este escoja y una vez sabemos la ciudad exacta, la busquemos en el json y saquemos el código de esta.

Por tanto, ¿Cómo realizo esa búsqueda en PHP de la ciudad en un JSON? El JSON tiene estas características:

```
[
 {
  "id": 707860,
  "name": "Hurzuf",
  "country": "UA",
  "coord": {
     "lon": 34.283333,
     "lat": 44.549999
  }
 },
 {
  "id": 519188,
  "name": "Novinki",
  "country": "RU",
  "coord": {
     "lon": 37.666668,
     "lat": 55.683334
  }
 }
]
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Ese json no esta bien formateado

Comment: Yo lo veo bien formateado.

Comment: Tiene muchas más ciudades, solo que añadí las dos primeras para ejemplificar.

Comment: Debes usar el método `json_decode($json_string, TRUE)` para pasar la cadena json a una variable con formato de array asociativo. ver: http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php, luego puedes recorrerlo iterando y extraer lo que necesites.

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que ya tienes el JSON en un array asociativo, podrias recorrerlo con un `foreach` y luego guardar los resultados que desees en otro array asociativo.  Luego puedes manipular los resultados como desees.  Algo asi:

```
$resultados = array();
$buscar = $_POST['buscar'];
foreach($ciudades as $i => $ciudad) {
    if(strpos($ciudad['name'], $buscar) != FALSE) {
        $resultados[$ciudad['id']] = $ciudad['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: De nada @EvelynGarcía y bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español

Comment: Tu respuesta es una guía muy grande para lo que estoy intentando hacer... pero tengo una duda muy grande... De donde salen las variables `$resultados` y `$ciudades`? Gracias de ante mano!